# A Specific Example about Parabolic PDE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

I am solving a PDE numerical problem. And I have already had a algorithm. However, it seems to be hard to find a specific example to test my solution. Could you please give me one?

The equation should be like that:
\begin{equation}
u_{t} = a^{2}u_{xx} + f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,0) = u_{0}(x)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = u(x + 1,t)
\end{equation}
Please tell me the $f(x)$ , $u_{0}(x)$ , $a$ and of course the real solution $u(x,t)$.

My try:
Use the Poisson Formula, I can get:
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x-\xi,t)u_{0}(\xi)\mathbb{d}\xi + \int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{d}\tau \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x-\xi,t-\tau)f(\xi,\tau)\mathbb{d}\xi
\end{equation}
where$$ K = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{\pi t}}\mathbb{e}^{-x^{2} / (4a^{2}t)}, & t > 0, \\
0, & t\leq 0
\end{array} 
\right.$$
To simplify it, I assume $f\equiv0$ and $u_{0}(x) = x$ in $ [0,1)$.
Then substitute it:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2a\sqrt{\pi t}}\mathbb{e}^{-(x-\xi)^{2} / (4a^{2}t)}u_{0}(\xi) \mathbb{d}\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{\pi t}}\mathbb{e}^{-(x+1-\xi)^{2} / (4a^{2}t)} u_{0}(\xi) \mathbb{d}\xi.
\end{equation}
Because of the periodic condition, the integration can become:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} \frac{1}{2a\sqrt{\pi t}}\mathbb{e}^{-(x-\xi)^{2} / (4a^{2}t)}(\xi - j) \mathbb{d}\xi = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} \frac{1}{2a\sqrt{\pi t}}\mathbb{e}^{-(x+1-\xi)^{2} / (4a^{2}t)}(\xi - j) \mathbb{d}\xi.
\end{equation}
But the integration is too tedious, maybe $u_{0}(x)$ can be more simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if $u$ is $1-$periodic, so is $f$. Thus, writing
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat u_k(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi ikx}, \quad $f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat f_k\,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi ikx},
$$
the PDE becomes:
$$
0=u_t-a^2u_{xx}-f=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\hat u_k(t)+(2\pi ka)^2\hat u_k(t)-\hat f_k\Big)\,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi ikx},
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\hat u_k(t)+(2\pi ka)^2\hat u_k(t)=\hat f_{\!\!k}, \quad\text{for all}\,\,\,k\in\mathbb Z,
$$
etc...

Comment: So the u(x,t) will be equal to the sum of infinite series, but it is hard to caculate it in the computer.

Comment: It is not so hard because the series converges extremely fast. You only need a small number of terms.